# Performance with SQL Server cursor in following application scenario

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I've wondered about how can I modify my application because I have performance problem. I have following application scenario. I've used C# console application with SQL Server.

**Application scenario:**

1. Select 15 000 unique UserId (INT)
2. Foreach this list of users and get list of documents (documentid) for every UserId. (*Perhaps 50 documents per one user.*)
3. Insert into database into a table called Permissions - UserId, DocumentsId - perhaps - 15 000 * 50 = 750 000 rows

**My scenario:**

1. I have create two stored procedures in SQL Server, first for select UserId's and second for get documents according userid and inserting into permissions table.

Stored procedure: `dbo.CreateDocumentPermissions`

```
declare @userId bigint

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE PermissionsCursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT UserId FROM dbo.[User]

    OPEN PermissionsCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM PermissionsCursor INTO @userId

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            BEGIN TRY
                EXEC dbo.SaveDocumentsPermissions @userId = @userId
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
                PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()
            END CATCH

            FETCH NEXT FROM PermissionsCursor INTO @userId
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH

BEGIN TRY             
    CLOSE PermissionsCursor
    DEALLOCATE PermissionsCursor                                  
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Stored Procedure: `dbo.SaveDocumentsPermissions`  @userId = @userId

```
  DECLARE @finalUserSet TABLE
        (
          documentId INT
        )


    DECLARE @userParentDepts TABLE
        (
          parentPath HIERARCHYID ,
          path HIERARCHYID ,
          organisationCode NVARCHAR(10) ,
          entityId BIGINT
        );

    WITH    ParentOTV_CTE ( parentPath, Path, Name, ItemId, organisationCode )
              AS ( SELECT   otv.ParentPath ,
                            otv.Path ,
                            otv.Text ,
                            otv.ItemId ,
                            otv.OrganisationCode
                   FROM     dbo.OrganisationTreeView AS otv
                   WHERE    otv.ItemId = @userId
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT   otv.ParentPath ,
                            otv.Path ,
                            otv.Text ,
                            otv.ItemId ,
                            otv.OrganisationCode
                   FROM     dbo.OrganisationTreeView AS otv
                            INNER JOIN ParentOTV_CTE AS potv ON potv.parentPath = otv.Path
                 )

        INSERT  INTO @userParentDepts
                ( parentPath ,
                  path ,
                  organisationCode ,
                  entityId
                )
                SELECT  otv.ParentPath ,
                        otv.Path ,
                        otv.organisationCode ,
                        otv.ItemId
                FROM    ParentOTV_CTE otv
                WHERE   otv.ParentPath IS NOT NULL

    INSERT  INTO @finalUserSet
            SELECT  d.DocumentId
            FROM    @userParentDepts dpts
                    INNER JOIN dbo.DocumentAudience da ON pa.OrganisationCode = dpts.organisationCode
                                                        AND da.OrgEntityId = dpts.entityId
                                                        AND da.Active = 1
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Documents] d ON da.DocumentId = d.DocumentId


    DELETE  FROM dbo.DocumentPermissions
    WHERE   UserId = @userId


    INSERT  INTO dbo.DocumentPermissions
            ( UserId,
              DocumentId
            )
    SELECT @userId, documentId FROM 
    @finalUserSet
```

Table structure - `DocumentPermissions`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DocumentPermissions]
(
    [DocumentPermissionId] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentId] [INT] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DocumentPermissions] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DocumentPermissionId] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I have a nonclustered index for `UserId, DocumentId`.

How can I improve my application scenario for better performance?

Comment: Modify your proc `dbo.SaveDocumentsPermissions` to accept a table-type parameter, scrap the cursor and pass a table variable to procedure containing UserIDs, will allow you a SET BASED processing of records rather then a Row By Row (performance Killer) processing.

Comment: How are determining the list of documents per user? Is that done within SaveDocumentPermissions? Do all UserIds have documents or are there some that don't? If some don't then surely there must be a way for you to only include UserIds with documents associated with them in your cursor.

Comment: Please include the text of your `dbo.SaveDocumentsPermissions` stored procedure. If there is an opportunity to modify this stored procedure to be set-based, you will likely see a performance increase.

Comment: I have two tables dbo.OrganisationStructure and dbo.DocumentsAudience. Author of document determined the departments in dbo.OrganisationStructure. This departments I saved into DocumentsAudience and I calculate using hierarchyid a permission. I've created the cursor because I only can calculate permissions for one user in query.

Comment: What's in OrganisationTreeView? Assuming it's a view it could cause a lot of issues. For basic performance tuning I would first check what statistics io says, and also check plan cache for I/O and cpu usage per statement

Comment: @JamesZ OrganisationTreeView is a view and this view only returns table dbo.OrganisationStructure with limited colums.

Comment: @Jenan I just saw this today. My apologies for the delayed response. It's not the cursor itself that is slowing down performance but the simple fact that you are looping through all of your users that is probably causing you grief. How many users are there?

Comment: I would take this to a test environment first, but the plan is to add the userid to each of your tables and statements in `dbo.SaveDocumentsPermissions` and then you can `TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DocumentPermissions` instead of `DELETE FROM dbo.DocumentPermissions`, which is much more time consuming.

Comment: FYI - Using set-based processes allows the compiler to utilize advanced algorithms which will far exceed the performance of loops.

Comment: @Jenan Are you able to display the create script for `OrganisationTreeView`?